# I am having an issu with sending message

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, twilio

this is the problem  , please help to find me a way to use send message function

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0lBk.png

Comment: twilio is not supporting sendmessage function

Comment: "I'm having issu" is really bad title, and your question isn't much better. Please take some time to write proper questions / descriptions of your issue. "Please help" is not a question either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looks like you might have the latest version of the C# library installed there, but you're trying to use the code for the previous version.

I recommend you check out the [documentation for sending messages with C#](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages?code-sample=code-send-a-message-with-an-image-url&code-language=cs&code-sdk-version=5.x).

The example for using C# looks like this:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Api.V2010.Account;
using Twilio.Types;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Example
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        const string accountSid = "YOUR_ACCOUNT_SID";
        const string authToken = "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var to = new PhoneNumber(PHONE_NUMBER);
        var message = MessageResource.Create(
            to,
            from: new PhoneNumber(TWILIO_NUMBER),
            body: "Hello world!",
            mediaUrl: mediaUrl);
        Console.WriteLine(message.Sid);
   }
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.